# pTemplate="filter" not showing on PrimeNG dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to display an input text on top of the drop-down item list, for the purpose to search the. I know there you can there is a functionality just for that (`<ng-template pTemplate="filter">`). But whatever I do, I can't manage to make it render.

HTML:

```jsx
<p-dropdown [options]="this.colaboradoresList" [(ngModel)]="this.currentColaborador" placeholder="Selecionar Colaborador" appendTo="body" filterBy="nomeCompleto" optionLabel="nomeCompleto">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
    <span class="p-float-label">
      <input id="search-box" type="text" pInputText (input)="this.onSearchInput($event)">
      <label for="search-box">Procurar Colaborador</label>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

TypeScript:

```ts
onSearchInput(event) {
  if (event.value.trim().length == 0 || event.value.trim() == '') {
    this.colaboradoresList = [];
    return;
  }

  this.searchColaboradores.next(event.value); /* GET request to api */
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

`this.colaboradoresList` is only supposed to be filled after I input something in the searchbar. It is initialized as `[]` (empty)

How is it looking:

[image: How is it looking]

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/inputtext

Comment: Have you checked that your list `this.colaboradoresList` actually gets set at any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the [filter]="true" flag.

Answer (score 0):

In your onSearchInput method I didn't see where it populates the `collaboratorsList`.

In the line below you should use 3 equals:
`if (event.value.trim().length === 0 || event.value.trim() === '')`